# fetch in react-native gives error when App goes in background state in iOS Platform

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

```
static fetchCall(request) {
    console.log('Request' + JSON.stringify(request))
    return fetch(AsynCall.BASE_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(request),
    }).
    then((response) => 
        response.json())
        .then((responseData) =>
            ResponseController.handleResponse(responseData),
        ).then(res => {
          return res
        })
        .catch((error) => {  
          throw (error)
        },
        )
  }
}
```

On Android its working fine in background, But iOS gives error in background.

"code": "ENSURLERRORDOMAIN-1005" , "message": "Network connection was lost"

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

That's because react-native doesn't support background tasks out of the box. Consider using a third-party library, like `react-native-background-fetch`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Also, image loading through any https links are getting failed in when app goes in background, is there anything which can help me with the background mode in iOS. On android everything is working fine in background.

Comment: I would suggest you the same what I did in my answer: use a third-party-lib that manages background tasks for any of them. Basically, if your app needs background tasks a lot, react-native is not the best choice of development platform. Consider looking at native development or using Flutter. Another way to solve your problem is tracking all your current fetches and putting flags when fetch is successfully finished. Read more about api that helps you manage when your app is in foreground or background mode: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate